# Is there a way to return a 5XX error from a node.js express basicAuth handler?

Tags: node.js, express

My express app uses the following basic auth function:

```
exports.basicAuth = express.basicAuth(function (user, pass, callback) {              
    findUserByEmail(user, function (err, account) {                                  
        var isPasswordMatch = false;                                                 
        log.info("Authenticate request user-pass: " + user + ":" + pass);            
        if (err) {                                                                   
            log.info("Error occurred when authenticate user: " + err);                                                                  
        }                                                                            
        if (account == null || account == undefined) {                               
            log.info("Account not found");                                           
        } else {                                                                     
            if (!isActive(account)) {                                                
                log.info("Account is not active");                                   
            }                                                                        
            if (account.password != encryptPassword(account.salt, pass)) {           
                log.info("Wrong pass");                                              
                isPasswordMatch = false;                                             
            } else {                                                                 
                isPasswordMatch = true;                                              
            }                                                                            
        }                                                                            

        var authenticated = err == null && account != null && account != undefined && isActive(account) && isPasswordMatch;
        callback(null, authenticated);                                          
    });                                                                              
});
```

Sometimes, when the server is overloaded the `findUserByEmail` request will fail. In this case, the function above causes the server to return a 401 error. Instead, I want to return a 5XX error code, so that clients know that there is a problem at the server, not necessarily with the credentials they passed. What is the best way to cause an error in findUserByEmail to return a 5XX error code instead of a 401?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with express to provide an actual answer, but I would think you might get the result you're looking for if you pass an actual error as the first argument to your `callback`

Comment: Nope, still returns a 401.

Comment: You could try just throwing an error inside the code.  If you have error handling middleware it will catch it, and you could throw a 500 in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I just wrapped the authentication handler in a standard request handler and send an error response if something goes wrong.

```
exports.basicAuth = function(req, res, next) {                                   
    express.basicAuth(function (user, pass, callback) {                          
        findUserByEmail(user, function (err, account) {                          
            var isPasswordMatch = false;                                         
            log.info("Authenticate request user-pass: " + user + ":" + pass);    
            if (err) {                                                           
                log.info("Error occurred when authenticate user");               
                res.send(500, { error: 'Unable to authenticate request' });      
                return;                                                          
            }             
            ...                                      
        });                                                                      
    })(req, res, next);                                                          
};
```